# Use Virtuoso triplestore as backend for WebProtégé?

Tags: protege, virtuoso

We have an OWL ontology on a Virtuoso SPARQL Endpoint with different services running (reading) on top of it. We want to offer ontology editing with WebProtégé but as far as we could find out, it stores it's data in a binary format. Is there any way to use a Virtuoso SPARQL Endpoint as a backend to WebProtégé?

Comment: As far as I can tell from WebProtégé documentation, it does not operate atop any triple/quad-store, but writes its data files to the filesystem, and not to any API (SPARQL, JDBC, etc.) supported by Virtuoso.  Have you asked the WebProtégé folks, as [their homepage advises](https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/WebProtege)?

Comment: @TallTed Thanks for the suggestion! I asked protege-user@lists.stanford.edu now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the horse's mouth](http://protege-project.136.n4.nabble.com/Use-Virtuoso-triplestore-as-backend-for-WebProtege-tp4669545p4669546.html) --

> There isn’t a way to do this.